# Combine dplyr group_by and approxfun/approx in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, interpolation, lm

I have a database containing the number of cells in different growth stages (enlarging and maturing). I only have data for certain days of the year (DOY). Sometimes there were no cells and next time I sampled there were already more than 2 cells. I wanted to know *when* did every growth stage start (Enlarging/Maturing > 1) and end (Enlarging/Maturing < 1). For that, I just wanted to make an interpolation between the two consecutive DOYs when there were no cells and when there was more than 2. This interpolation needs to have a daily scale (DOY 1-365) so I know which exact day the onset and ending of every growth stage took place. The database looks like this (simplified reproducible example):

```
df <- data.frame("Year" = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012,
                            2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013,
                            2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013),
                 "Tree" = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 41, 41,
                            41, 41, 41, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53),
                 "DOY" = c(65, 97, 125, 177, 214, 65, 97, 125, 177, 214,
                           61, 99, 118, 166, 221, 61, 99, 118, 166, 221),
                 "Enlarging" = c(0, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 3, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0),
                 "Maturing" = c(0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 0))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.factor(Year),
         Tree = as.factor(Tree),
         DOY = as.numeric(DOY),
         Enlarging = as.numeric(Enlarging),
         Maturing = as.numeric(Maturing))

print(df)
   Year Tree DOY Enlarging Maturing
1  2012   15  65         0        0
2  2012   15  97         2        0
3  2012   15 125         4        3
4  2012   15 177         5        7
5  2012   15 214         0        0
6  2012   22  65         0        0
7  2012   22  97         3        0
8  2012   22 125         6        3
9  2012   22 177         3        4
10 2012   22 214         0        0
11 2013   41  61         0        0
12 2013   41  99         5        3
13 2013   41 118         4        6
14 2013   41 166         4        8
15 2013   41 221         0        0
16 2013   53  61         0        0
17 2013   53  99         4        0
18 2013   53 118         7        4
19 2013   53 166         5        7
20 2013   53 221         0        0
```

I was planning to use the `approxfun` or `approx` functions to do that because I saw they can do what I need, but I have never tried it. The problem is that I have 2 growth stages, different trees sampled and different years of samplings, so I wanted to use the `dplyr` package (something like `group_by(Year, Tree)`) because it's easy for me to use. But I have no idea about how to write the syntax of what I want to do. I don't mind using another aproach, like a linear model (`lm`) + `predict` to predict the onset (cells > 1) and ending (cells < 1) of every growth stage, but again, I don't know how to do it. I would like to obtain a new dataframe similar to the one above but with the interpolated data, or a dataframe containing the onset and ending DOYs for every growth stage for every Tree, every Year.

Thank you so much in advance if anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you provide a sample out so that we understand exactly what the calculation is.  For example for Tree 15 and year 2012 what is the expected answer?

Comment: Very similar examples using `lm` here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: Hi @Dave2e , I want to know the starting and ending dates for every growth stage sepparately. Tree 15 from 2012 for example: on DOY 65 there were no cells and on day 97 there were two. I wanted to interpolate the daily value of nº of cells in every growth stage to know the onset and ending, maybe something like: Enlarging cells - DOY 65: 0.000 cells, DOY 66: 0.022, DOY 67: 0.053... DOY 79: 0.97, DOY 80: 1,02... the criteria would be to calculate the first DOY where Enlarging cells > 1, same for Maturing. In that case for this example, Enlarging stage would start on DOY 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.
The method is to split the original data frame by year and tree into a list of data frames.
Then taking the Day of year and the Enlarging/maturing columns perform an approximately to find the day of year when Enlarging/maturing=0.  Below I am using either a linear approximation of cubic spline (commented out).
Of course is assuming valid incoming data, no repeated measurements, data is chronological order, etc

```
library(dplyr)

onset <- function(x, doy) {
    #Looking for the last 0 day before onset.
    nonzero <- which(x !=0 )
    nonzero <- c((nonzero[1]-1), nonzero) #adds the first non zero term
    
    x <- x[nonzero]
    doy <- doy[nonzero]
    #approximation options
    #linear
     estimate <- approx(x, doy, xout=1)$y
   #cubic spline
   #estimate <- spline(x, doy, xout=1)$y    
   return (estimate)
}

#split year and tree into a list of data frames
treelist <-split(df, paste(df$Year, df$Tree))

 dfs <- lapply(treelist, function(tree){
    EnlargeOnset <- onset(tree$Enlarging, tree$DOY)
    
    MatureOnset <- onset(tree$Maturing, tree$DOY)

    out <- data.frame(Year=tree$Year[1], Tree=tree$Tree[1], EnlargeOnset, MatureOnset)
 })
answers <- bind_rows(dfs)
 
#answers
  Year Tree EnlargeOnset MatureOnset
1 2012   15        81.00   106.33333
2 2012   22        89.00   106.33333
3 2013   41        81.25    73.66667
4 2013   53        70.50   103.75000
```

Comment: Hello @Dave2e , this is exactly what I wanted as an output. Well, not only the onset of every growth stage but also the ending, just as the #answers output shows. I tried this in my own script and everything worked until the `dfs` part nearle the end. I got the next error: `Error in approx(x, doy, xout = 1) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`. Do you know what can be?

Comment: I was checking the script and in the `dfs` section, should it not be `df$Enlarging` and `df$Mature` instead of `tree$Enlarging` and `tree$Mature`? Changing that gave me no error this time, but I get the same onset for ALL trees instead of differents onset dates for each tree. @Dave2e

Comment: The first answer is most likely due to insufficient data for one of the trees, it never reach the point of >1.  Second comment: Yes it is suppose be to “tree” since that is the variable in the function call.  You will need to add some error checking to ensure there are 2 data points for the approx function. The original data frame is split into smaller ones and the small data frames are passed into the lapply function named as “treel

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think there are one or two trees that never reach the point of > 1. You were incredibly helpful! @Dave2e

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood this solve the data processing step - I am using just the percentage of past days to multiply with first value per group where the data has been made long or tidy: Enlarging and Maturing are converted one column with numeric values and one informing which "Stage" it belongs to.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    # build groupings
    dplyr::group_by(Year, Tree) %>%
    # since I do not know the full data, first calculate date to order by 
    # since possibly some Tree samples extend over the years end 
    dplyr::mutate(dt = as.Date(paste0(Year, "-01-01")) + DOY) %>% 
    # arrange data to perform correct calculations and get nice print output
    dplyr::arrange(Year, Tree, dt) %>% 
    # calculate event staring or stopping variable
    dplyr::mutate(event = dplyr::case_when(Enlarging < Maturing ~ "stopping", 
                                           Enlarging > Maturing ~ "starting", 
                                           TRUE ~ NA_character_), 
                 # per group generate column of prior date
                 lag_dt = dplyr::lag(dt)) %>% 
    # make data longer or tidy so you have new colum for the stage and only one value column
    tidyr::pivot_longer(Enlarging:Maturing, names_to = "Stage", values_to = "value") %>% 
    # build grouping now including the stage
    dplyr::group_by(Stage, Year, Tree) %>% 
    # make sure order is correct once again
    dplyr::arrange(Stage, Year, Tree, dt) %>% 
    # get only rows where value is larger than one
    dplyr::filter(value > 1) %>%
    # get first row of each group only
    dplyr::slice_min(order_by = dt, n = 1) %>% 
    # make a nestes list of date sequence
    dplyr::mutate(all_dt = list(seq(lag_dt, dt, by='1 day'))) %>% 
    # unnest it into the tibble/data.frame
    tidyr::unnest(cols = c(all_dt)) %>% 
    # correct value to final and first else NA according to date
    dplyr::mutate(value = dplyr::case_when(dt == all_dt ~ value,                  
                                           lag_dt == all_dt ~ 0, 
                                           TRUE ~ NA_real_), 
                  # perform calculation using row number per group 
                  # (equivalent to running day)
                  # to build the percentage of progess
                  # multiply with max value per group
                  # possibly you do not want to use -1
                  linear = (dplyr::row_number() -1)/max(dplyr::row_number() -1) * max(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    # ungroup to prevent unwantes behaviour down stream (possibly you do not want to ungroup depending on next steps)
    dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 261 x 10
   Year  Tree    DOY dt         event    lag_dt     Stage     value all_dt     linear
   <fct> <fct> <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <date>      <dbl>
 1 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging     0 2012-03-06 0     
 2 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-07 0.0625
 3 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-08 0.125 
 4 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-09 0.188 
 5 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-10 0.25  
 6 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-11 0.312 
 7 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-12 0.375 
 8 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-13 0.438 
 9 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-14 0.5   
10 2012  15       97 2012-04-07 starting 2012-03-06 Enlarging    NA 2012-03-15 0.562 
# ... with 251 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is not exactly what I was looking for, let me explain. First of all, I want to know the starting and ending dates for every growth stage sepparately. Take the Tree 15 from 2012 for example. On DOY 65 there were no cells and on day 97 there were two. I would like to make a daily interpolation - how many enlarging cells were on DOY 66, on DOY 67, 68, 69... 95, 96-, and same for the thickening ones. And then the same interpolation between the two last dates where there were Enlarging or Thickening cells and when there were no more. Is it possible? @DPH

Comment: @DavidAlmagro from what I understood of your question the example you gave is not valid since there where not more than 2 cells... meaning we should use a criteria of more than one (aka at least two) instead of more than two (aka a least three)? By thickening I deduce you mean "maturing" where the same criteria of at least 2 should be applied? The summation of "enlarging" and "maturing" does not matter of all, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant maturing, not thickening, and that's correct, no summation of enlarging and maturing. I'm not sure I understood the question, but the criteria would be to calculate the first DOY where Enlarging cells > 1, same for Maturing. Don't know if it's possible, maybe I should use a linear model, but I was planning to create a new daily dataframe (something like `seq(1, 365, 1)`) in which I can extract the daily value of nº of cells in every growth stage. For example, for Tree 15: DOY 65: 0.000, DOY 66: 0.022, DOY 67: 0.053... DOY 79: 0.97, DOY 80: 1,02.. in that case start = DOY 80 @DPH

Comment: @DavidAlmagro I am at work right now but I will get back to you in something like 4 or 5 hours... should be possible to solve the data wrangling you need and interpolate though I am afraid that the number of cells is relatively low and there are not many observations. In general concerning which modelling approach I is recommended or best practice is not a stackoverflow topic - there are other communities for this specific type of question like this onehttps://stats.stackexchange.com/ (also it might be something very domain specific)... let us solve the wrangling first

Comment: Thank you so much @DPH really. My real database has actually 20-25 bi-weekly observations per year, 6 trees and more than 10 years ob observations, but for this example I wanted to keep things simple so it's easier to understand.

Comment: @DavidAlmagro have a look at the altered answer

Comment: sorry for not answering before, I'm going to try this and see if works for my database, thank you so much, this was incredibly helpful and I learnt a few new things I didn't know